# How to display an <img> in Vue.js only if the image url exists?

Tags: javascript, html, pug, vue.js

I'm getting a bunch of tweets from the Twitter API. Some tweets have images attached to them, some don't.

Currently, I use this code to display the image of a tweet:

```vue
<template lang="jade">
  div Tweet text
    img(:src='tweet.entities.media[0].media_url', width='100%')
</template>

<script>
import store from './store.js';

export default {
  name: 'tweet',
  data () {
    return {
      tweet : store.selectedTweet
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The problem is that this only works if the tweet actually has at least one image. If it has no image, I get an exception because `tweet.entities.media` is undefined.

How can I fix this so that the `<img>` is only used if there is actually an image available in the tweet's entity value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `v-if`:

```
<template>
    <div class="Tweet text">
        <img :src="tweet.entities.media[0].media_url" width="100%" v-if="tweet.entities.media" />
    </div>
</template>
```

Using `v-if` will stop the img element to be rendered.

Comment: Very elegant solution! Thanks!

Comment: I edited my response sorry, you need to make the test on the length of the array to check if there is more than one item: `v-if="tweet.entities.media.length"`

Comment: Except if the media property doesn't even exist if there is no image

Comment: If you look closely to my original question you will see that the Twitter API will return 'undefined' for `tweet.entities.media` if there is no image: "If it has no image, I get an exception because tweet.entities.media is undefined.", so checking for .length will not work (It actually didn't work. I just tested it).

Answer (score 1):

In string templates, for example Handlebars, we would write a conditional block like this:

```
{{#if tweet.entities.media}}
    img(:src='tweet.entities.media[0].media_url', width='100%')
{{/if}}
```

In Vue, we use the v-if directive to achieve the same:

```
<template>
    <div class="Tweet text">
        <img :src="tweet.entities.media[0].media_url" width="100%" v-if="tweet.entities.media" />
    </div>
</template>
```

Here you find the [Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)